# Why converter is not getting called

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have converter to change my collection to list of values and their type.My converter accepts a class type and returns an IEnumerable

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Model,Converter={StaticResource PropConverter}}"/>
```

my partial class code is

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Model Model
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        Model=new Model();

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

where as if I change my  code and xaml like this it calls the convereter

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext=new Model();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PropConverter}}"/>
```

Can you please tell me the reason why this is happening.I prefer to do the first way but somehow it does not call converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first example:

It's not working because you don't assign DataContext so it's equal to null.

You can fix it by assign to DataContext value:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Model Model
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Model=new Model();

        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

And now below binding will be working:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Model,Converter={StaticResource PropConverter}}"/>
```

The better option is learning [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and assign to DataContext `ViewModel`:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Model = new Model();
    }
    public Model Model
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

View:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MainViewModel _vm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _vm = new MainViewModel();
        this.DataContext = _vm;
    }
}
```